# Raster graphics disadvantages of HTML/CSS presentations

Tags: html, css, graphics, presentation, impress.js

Many programmers prefer the idea of building presentation with just the help of a text editor instead of using a GUI tool.

With the help of the JavaScript code provided by impress.js, it is possible to create an animated presentation using HTML/CSS. The project provides an "impress"ing example and many people wrote enthusiastic comments about it.

However, I am a bit worried about the inherent limitations of this approach: Lengths in HTML/CSS are specified in a raster graphics model. Therefore, one must know the resolution of the beamer (screen or other displaying device) to design the presentation in an adequate way. Scaling the presentation afterwards (and porting to different devices) seems to be difficult.

Doesn't it make more sense to use vector graphic tools like the LaTeX Beamer class or the Inkscape plugins JessyInk or Sozi, which allow for better scaling?

Any comment and oppinion is appreciated.

Comment: Dimensions in CSS are not bound to pixel values.  You can certainly use relative values all you want... percent, ems, etc.

Comment: Yes, I think you're right. But the problem still remains how to scale the presentation correctly if you don't know the resolution of your displaying device in advance. A PDF is simply scaled to fullscreen, but even though CSS might be able to use relative units like em, one seems to have to adjust it manually.

Comment: What is the problem?  Can you give a concrete example of what you are talking about?  I don't see any issue with the standard size values given.

Comment: In the impress.js example [link](https://github.com/bartaz/impress.js/blob/master/index.html) there is for example the following line of code: <div class="step slide" data-x="1000" data-y="-1500">